# Multiple XP machines bluescreening simultaneously

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

What, other than magic, could cause multiple similarly configured XP Pro machines (non-domain joined, windows update disabled, no scheduled tasks) to bugcheck within 15 minutes of each other?  The error message recorded in the event log is reproduced below:

Error code 10000050, parameter1 bc6ffff0, parameter2 00000000, parameter3 bf84cd45, parameter4 00000000.

Note: Windows update being disabled is *not* my choice.  These are not under my control and are used in factory automation.

Note: I have considered a power anomaly, but there are many other similarly configured machines that had no apparent issues.

Comment: Some kind of un-patched vulnerability that permits a basic Denial of Service?

Comment: Factory automation, and no updates. That's going to cost your company big time when somebody gets in to those boxes and wreaks havoc.

Comment: Gets in? My guess is they're already in.

Comment: What common software do the machines have? Norton AV by any chance?

Comment: I am well aware of the reasons that updates should be performed.  Your arguments are the same used when convincing business owners that the system should be replaced.  The replacement is in development.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, the vendor is wholly against A/V.  Again, their ignorance of security or sanity shows itself.  This is the same vendor who has never heard of a `WHERE` clause and requires gigabit networking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first thing to do is to look up the reason for the bluescreens - I swear by [whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) and [bluescreen](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) view - these either interpret or look up the precise errors easily. I'd look at each system seperately - It might be a co-incidence that these systems crashed together. If its a one off incident it may not be worth following up on - else, well thats the right place to start.

Once you've looked at individual systems *then* hunting down a common cause is easier.

Comment: RDPDD.DLL at RDPDD!DrvDisableSurface+0x63.  Looks like a bug with XP SP3 and changing resolutions with RDP Clients.  See http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;963038&sd=rss&spid=3223